# How to set displayed text for a HTML anchor tag using Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I would like to dynamically change the text displayed for a HTML anchor tag. So, for example if I have the following in my markup -

```
<a class="point" style="font-family:courier" wicket:id="link">[+]</a>
```

I want to change the '[+]' to something else. Currently the code fragment looks like this:

```
            equipmentFamilyName.add(new Link<String>("link") {

                @Override
                protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
                    String id = "link" + equipmentFamilyName.getModelObject();
                    tag.put("onclick", "toggle('" + collapsibleId + "','" + id + "')");
                    tag.put("id", id);
                }

            @Override
            public void onClick() {

            }
            });
```

Which just adds various attributes. I tried using a model associated with the Link object like this

```
            IModel<String> linkModel = new Model<String>("-");
            equipmentFamilyName.add(new Link<String>("link", linkModel) {
                ...
```

But that had no effect on the displayed text i.e. I still get '[+]' shown on my web page.
Any suggestions or code examples clarifying how to do this would be much appreciated.

Edit: Following the pointers in the comments, I added a method to override onComponentTagBody(). I now have a solution to this for our current version of Wicket (1.4.17).

```
                @Override
                protected void onComponentTagBody(final MarkupStream markupStream, final ComponentTag openTag) {
                    replaceComponentTagBody(markupStream, openTag, "[-]");
                }
```

Comment: you need to add a <span> inside the <a> and add a Label to the Link in Java.

Comment: You don't actually need a span, you can use the <wicket:container> tag too, which is stripped out in deployment mode.

Comment: By the way, if you're overriding the `onComponentTag()` anyway, you don't have to use the `Link` class at all, and you can replace the tag body with your model text.

Comment: I solved this by overriding onComponentTagBody

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Wicket 1.5 then this is quite easy: link.setBody(IModel).
The model's object will be used as link's body.

Comment: Thanks. We're currently using Wicket 1.4.17.